# How to automatically add xsd:attribute to xsd:complexType in Apache XMLBeans?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xmlbeans

We're running into some trouble with supplied XSDs of the following kind:

```
<xsd:complexType name="foo">
    ...
    <xsd:attribute name="version" fixed="1" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

The XML-Result is then expected look something like this:

```
<foo version="1">...</foo>
```

Since this is not how fixed attribute values are actually supposed to work XMLBeans will not generate such a result for us by default. We have hundreds of XSDs like this with varying versions and want to avoid adding them all by hand.

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically determine the values of fixed attributes of a given XMLObject so we can add them generically?

Comment: Did you look at http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/conIntroToTheSchemaTypeSystem.html

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how we missed that. We already had a SchemaType but somehow missed the link to the corresponding SchemaAttributeModel which seems to be all that's needed for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/conIntroToTheSchemaTypeSystem.html) provided by Petru Gardea's comment above you can access information about an XMLObjects schema, its attributes and their default values by using the SchemaTypeSystem.